# Firebase on android not retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been able to successfully upload and delete data from my firebase repo using the guide here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html

However if I try and retrieve the data using the the Firebase guide here:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

the app activity just hangs - there is no call back to onDataChange or onCancel. I am using the exact code in the example which has worked until this point in the guide (in my Activity onCreate() method):

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

There is data at the example URL so should work. I am running on a phone running Android 4.0.3.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Riz

Edit: I tried on my Samsung Note 4 running Android 5.1.1 and Firebase works fine. Doesn't work on my Huawei running Android 4.0.3. Something to do with the Android version?

Edit 2: So it turns out the answer below was right after all. I found an old bit of code in one of my helper classes that was pausing the thread whilst it waited for something. I rewrote it to be truly asynchronous and it fixed the problem. Many thanks - I have accepted the answer.

Comment: There is a **very** good chance that the `CallBackSignaler` is simply blocking the main thread and hanging your app. See [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33204705/209103).

Comment: See my answer below. I have edited the question to remove it was a distraction.

Comment: I have accepted the answer as you were right after all - see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronizing data from Firebase is an asynchronous operation. Trying to wait for that data is not a good idea.

Your `CallbackSignaler` is blocking the `onDataChange()` from being called. If you remove the signaler, you'll see that the data is loaded, `onDataChange()` gets called and the value is logged.

See my answer to this question: [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener/33204705#33204705)

Comment: Thanks. It's not the signaler as I only put that in once I realised it was hanging to check for the callback without having to resort to the debugger. All my classes dealing with persistence are asynchronous by design - the callback signaler is just a debugging tool for problems like this.

Comment: Is your device connected to the internet? Check for airplane mode or [monitor `.info/connected`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state)

Comment: I have created a new clean project in Android studio with only the Firebase example inside the MainActivity. It seems to work on both phones fine now. I am not sure what is going on but there's a bunch of asynchronous stuff going on in my main app when I first fire it up as data is loaded. I'm wondering if there is some threading issue related to the answer you gave initially after all...

Comment: So it turns out you were right after all. I found an old bit of code in one of my helper classes that was pausing the thread whilst it waited for something. I rewrote it to be truly asynchronous and it fixed the problem. Many thanks - I have accepted the answer.

Comment: Good to hear! Now go and continue hacking with Firebase!